# How to make a while loop faster in python?

Tags: python

I am trying to make a script that figures out the least number divisible by numbers from 1 to 20 without any remainder. Apparently it works well with finding the least number that can be divided from 1 to 10 which is 2520, but for the former problem it takes a lot of time to actually find it because the number is much bigger than 2520 (232792560). So is there anyway to make that process faster, I am totally new to Python by the way. Here is the code I used:

```
num = 1
oper = 1
while oper <= 20:
    y = num % oper
    if y == 0:
        oper += 1
    else:
        num += 1
        oper = 1
print(num)
```

Comment: Find a different algorithm. It won’t save you a lot of time by using a library in this case. Think about integer factorization and using prime numbers instead of just increasing a variable one every loop

Comment: At the very least, `oper = 1` is a waste of time: *all* numbers are divisible by 1. Similarly, there's no point checking the odd numbers: none of them will be divisible by 2, let alone the larger even divisors. Start with `num = 2`, reset `oper = 2` for each number, and increment `num += 2`.

Comment: You're looking for the [least common multiple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple) of your numbers. There are many algorithms to calculate it much more efficiently than your brute force way .

Answer (score 1):

```
from math import gcd
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
lcm = a[0]
for i in a:
  lcm = lcm*i//gcd(lcm, i)
print(lcm)
```

Your algorithm is quite slow and will not work for quite large numbers efficiently.
This will find the lcm for each number and multiply it to the previous number.

Comment: There's no need to make a copy of `a`.

Comment: @chepner is correct. For more context, he is speaking specifically on `a[:]`, which should just be `a`.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it using [numpy](https://numpy.org/):

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.arange(1,21)
t = np.lcm.reduce(arr)
```

also see these [examples](https://www.w3schools.com/Python/numpy_ufunc_lcm.asp)